# I have recorded a script in Jmeter and want to parameterize the variables (username,password)

Tags: csv, variables, jmeter

I have set up Csv Data set Config and point to the csv file, when i run the test I am unable to see the data set for this variable, rather I am seeing an encrypted for username and password just showing as variables names and can not see the data being pulled from the csv file.

[CSV Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BegfF.png)

[username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OFXN.png)

[encrypted value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJbpd.png)

[password showing as variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOcmd.png)

I was expecting to see different username and password being used for different thread user.

Comment: Please do not put sample textual information as linked images. Use code tags instead and put these directly into the question. Guides of syntax is available on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your `LoadUsers.csv` file is a **real** [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and not a binary file originating form [MS Excel](https://www.office.com/launch/Excel) or equivalent?

Try opening it using a text editor like [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Notepad) and make sure that it looks like:

```
username1,password1
username2,password2
username3,password3
etc.
```

The file has to be **text**-based one, otherwise CSV Data Set Config won't work.

Also double check S[haring Mode of your CSV Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) as with non-default value you might get non-expected behaviour.